# System.currentTimeMills Execution time

Tags: java, performance

we are using one web service which works usually in 30-40 ms time.Inside that web service we are calling System.currentTimeMills for 38 times for calculating the time taken in various methods inside that service.

i just wanted to know if it is feasible to call this method more then 38 times from a code which is taking less then 40 ms ?? what is the overhead associated with this method ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's absolutely feasible to call it *hundreds of thousands* of times in that period. It doesn't have a huge amount of overhead - but it's not what you should be calling for time measurement anyway. Use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead, which is specifically designed for accurately measuring elapsed execution time, rather than telling the current wall time.

As a rough measure of the overhead, on my laptop, after JIT warmup, it takes about 14 milliseconds to call `System.nanoTime()` a million times. So calling it 38 times in the course of 40 milliseconds won't be much of an issue (assuming your system has about the same overhead; it may well depend greatly on hardware and OS).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a benchmark for your particular case - check how much does it take to run without time measurements.